# How do I use the object I get from Perl's Image::MetaData::JPEG?

Tags: perl

I am using the Image::MetaData::JPEG module to read an image's header information. I have the following:

```
my @files = </dir/*jpg>;

for (@files) {

my $image = new Image::MetaData::JPEG( $_ ) or die $!;
print $image . "\n"; 
}
```

This returns "Image::MetaData::JPEG=HASH(0x189b218)".

I've read through the module but how do I actually get the header info in a usable format?

Comment: Minor OT style note: "new Image::MetaData::JPEG($_)" is better written as "Image::MetaData::JPEG->new($_)", the indirect object notation is frowned upon. "new" isn't an operator in Perl, it is simply a class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print $image` prints the representation of the object along with its Hash address.

Read [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-MetaData-JPEG/lib/Image/MetaData/JPEG.pod) to see what you need.

Try `print $file->get_description();`

Comment: @ginius, no idea about that. For my original question I just googled it for you. The documentation is there, try to read it.